# Custom Taxonomy not working front side Woocommerce

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I have created a custom taxonomy for woocommerce product.

```
function add_hunts_type(){
 // Car Hunts
    $cHunt_labels = array(
        'name'              => __( 'Hunts', 'pixar' ),
        'singular_name'     => __( 'Hunt', 'pixar' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Hunts', 'pixar' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Hunts', 'pixar' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Hunt', 'pixar' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Hunt:', 'pixar' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Hunt', 'pixar' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Hunt', 'pixar' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Hunt', 'pixar' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Hunt', 'pixar' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Hunts', 'pixar' ),
    );
    $cHunt_args = array(
    'labels' => $cHunt_labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'carhunt' )
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'car_Hunt', 'product', $cHunt_args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_hunts_type', 0 );

    /* Flush rewrite rules for custom post types. */
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'flush_rewrite_rules' );
```

This is working when I login into admin.When want to try from  front end its not working.

- I have change parmalinks
- I have delete htaccess and regernate  it.
- I have other inbulit thing its working properly.

Please let me know if I miss something.

Answer (score 0):

Add an already registered taxonomy to an object type.

```
function add_hunts_type(){
/*Taxonomy details*/

register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'carhunt', 'product' );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy_Hunt' );
```